# Intellij reports Rust toolchain not installed, even though I just installed it

Tags: intellij-idea, rust, toolchain

I'm programming Rust in IntelliJ, on Windows 10. Trying to switch to the nightly channel so I can use some nightly features. But I can't get it to compile in nightly. This picture says it all:

[image]

On the right, we have IntelliJ telling me: error: toolchain 'nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc' is not installed

On the left, we have me just having had installed nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.

I've tried restarting my computer, IDE, uninstalling and reinstalling, etc. I've tried setting path variables, in my system, and in the IntelliJ run config. I'm still bamboozled.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the output when you run `rustup show` in that Rust project's directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I install Rust using [rustup](https://www.rustup.rs/) using Powershell while in the directory, it works. It doesn't work when I install Rust through the installer executable.